# Calling [ADSI] with external parameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am not very familiar with powershell scripting and I'm stuck on this problem - 
I need to make some operations on object retrieved like this:

```
$object = [ADSI]'LDAP://CN=Test User,OU=Dept,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=org'
...
$object.Commit()
```

this works fine, but I have to use distinguished name stored in variable - my test script looks like this, but its not working:

```
$object = [ADSI]'LDAP://$variable'
...
$object.Commit()
```

the first call to [ADSI] itself doesn't cause error, but any following operation crashes with message:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "commit": "The server is not operational.
"
At line:1 char:10
+ $object.commit <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

I'm pretty sure, that the parameter is sent in some wrong way, but I don't know, how to fix it, can anybody help?

tahnks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$object = [ADSI]"LDAP://$variable"
```

Single quotes don't expand variables.